# Mutiple Threading in the eyes of I/O operations?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I was thinking...

Does Multithreading using c#  in I/O operations ( lets say copying many files from c`:\1\` to `c:\2\` ) , will have performance differences rather than doing the operation - sequential ?

The reason why im struggle with myself is that an IO operation finally  - is One item which has to do work. so even if im working in parallel - he will still execute those copy orders as sequential...

or maybe my assumption is wrong ?

in that case is there any benefit of using multithreaded copy to :

- copy many small file ( sum  4GB)
- copy 4 big files ( sum 4 gb , 1000 mb each)

thanks

Comment: I'd have to test it but my _guess_ would be that if it's going to the same hard drive, there's not going to be much difference. Multiple locations (one per thread, for example) would probably be helpful, but you're going to be more I/O bound if all the threads go to the same drive.

Comment: This is something you can try and let the rest of us know the benchmark / result :-)

Comment: Copying files will typically not be CPU bound (unless you're doing some heavy work during the copy), so adding threads is not likely to add any benefit.

Comment: so how come - CMD's robocopy is to be documented as robust multithreaded copy operation which speed up copying ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir I don't know how Robocopy is implemented, but the actual copying is not done by the your application, so adding multiple threads will most likely not have the desired effect. I imagine that they use async I/O calls which prevent the calling thread from blocking. If all you do is add threads and make blocking calls, you're only adding overhead.

Comment: Actually, this is easy to test, since it's essentialy a test of the OS disk I/O system and very little to do with C#.  Create two threads that copy a lot of files and run them separately and then together.  Why easy - use two command-line windows and a batch file that copies, say, a whole folder. Two CMD is two processes and, so, two threads.  Type in the bat name on each to get them ready, then quickly click/enter both of 'em up. It may make take twice as long, it may take more than twice because of the disk thrashing - try it!  If it's less than twice as long, copying with two threads is OK

Comment: Even if more than one thread accesses the same drive, it is possible for the disk I/O system to make optimizations IF it knows a set of disk locations where I/O has been requested, (ie. there are multiple threads requesting disk I/O), it can serve up the physically-closest file data first. Someone needs to try this copying, both on a spinner and SSD, to see what really happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like others says, it has to be measured against concrete application context.

But just would like to invite an attention on this. 
Every time you copy a file the permission of Write access to destination location is checked, which is slow.

All of us met a case when you have to copy/paste a sequence of already compressed files, and if you them compress again into one big *ZIP* file, so the total compressed size is not significally smaller then the sum of all content, the IO operation will be executed a **way** faster. (Just try it, you will see a huge difference, if you didn't do it before).

So I would **assume** (again it has to be measured on concrete system, mine are just guesses) that having one big file write on single disk, will be faster the a lot of small files.

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi tigran  , and where the multithreaded part can help me here ( if any) ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: on **coping/moving** files, **imo** you will *not* get any real benefits if you use multithreading.

Comment: so how come - CMD's robocopy is to be documented as robust multithreaded copy operation which speed up copying ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir: **may be**, it's during coping the stuff on *different* drives. In this way, you can in multiple threads contemporary write a data on different disks, network drives whatever...

Comment: @RoyiNamir: check this out: [Multi-threaded robocopy for faster copies](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2009/12/07/multi-threaded-robocopy-for-faster-copies.aspx) and [Windows 7: Robocopy is Multi Threaded!](http://everydaynerd.com/microsoft/windows-7-robocopy-is-multi-threaded). The last one even with measuring. But note that both of them write about *network* data transmission. So basic speedup, imo, in this case is not in multithreaded-data-*writing*, but in multithreaded-data-*trasmission*. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Multithreading with files is not so much about the CPU but about IO. This means that totally different rules apply. Different devices have different characterstics:

1. Magnetic disks like sequential IO
2. SSDs like sequential or parallel random IO (mine has 4 hardware "threads")
3. The network likes many parallel operations to amortize latency

Answer (score 2):

I'm no expert in hard-disk related questions, but maybe this will shred some light for you:

Windows is using the NTFS file system. This system doesn't "like" too much small files, for example, under 1kb files. It will "magically" make 100 files of 1kb weight 400kb instead of 100kb. It is also VERY slow when dealing which a lot of "small" files. Therefore, copying one big file instead of many small files of the same weight will be much faster.

Also, from my personal experience and knowledge, Multithreading will NOT speed up the copying of many files, because the actual hardware disk is acting like one unit, and can't be sped up by sending many requests at the same time (it will process them one by one.)

Comment: It will process them one-by-one but, it using multi-threads to access different files allows the disk I/O system to make the optimization of satisfying the mechanically-nearest request first, so improving overall I/O performance.  Disk controlers and drivers are, in themselves, 'intelligent' multi-threaded I/O subsystems and, if you can, you should let them work to the best of their ability.